# Modificar texto de item de Listview de adaptador personalizado

Tags: android, android-listview, alertdialog, android-adapter

Tengo un Lisview en donde los ítems personalizados poseen un Button(entre otros componentes). El Button muestra un AlertDialog.Builder con una lista dinámica de opciones:

1. Si selecciona la ultima opción de la lista: cierra el AlertDialog.Builder actual y abre un nuevo AlertDialog, solicitando se ingrese un valor en una caja de texto.
2. Si selecciona cualquier otro elemento de la lista dinámica: cierra el AlertDialog.Builder actual.

Sea cual sea la opción seleccionada, el Button del Listview debe modificar su texto según lo seleccionado.

El problema se presenta en el Adapter del Listview, específicamente en el método getView. Al modificar el ViewHolder obtengo el error: **la variable ViewHolder no es final.**

¿Cómo se logra modificar el texto de un botón de un ítem de Listview, según lo seleccionado/ingresado de un Builder/AlertDialog que el mismo botón mostró?

Muestro parte relevante del código:

```
...
AlertDialog.Builder bprecios;
AlertDialog adnuevoprec;
...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.it_selectitem, null);         
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.precio = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_sa_prec);
            holder.precio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add("Precio 1");
                    list.add("Precio 2");                   
                    list.add("** mostrar otro dialog **");
                    CharSequence[] items = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);

                    bprecios.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                            if(item == list.size() - 1){ // el ultimo elemento
                                et_nuevoprecio = new EditText(act);
                                et_nuevoprecio.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
                                adnuevoprec = new AlertDialog.Builder(act)
                                .setMessage("Ingrese Nuevo Precio [S/.]")
                                .setTitle("Nuevo Precio")
                                .setView(et_nuevoprecio)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        holder.precio.setText(String.format("%.2f",et_nuevoprecio.getText()));// ERROR HOLDER NO FINAL
                                    }
                                })                               
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                                .create();

                            }else{
                                holder.precio.setText("");  // ERROR HOLDER NO FINAL                            
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();                
                        }
                    }).show();
                }
            });
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        }
        ...
        //Valor texto que se muestra por primera vez en los items del ListView.
        holder.precio.setText(String.format("%.2f",         miLista.get(position).getPreciocontado())); 
        ...
    return convertView;
    }
```

Tal vez existan mejores formas de realizar una modificación del texto de un componente de un item de un Listview sin necesidad de utilizar AlertDialog, se espera no salir del Activity del ListView para modificar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

@Oz92, solo debes agregar la palabra final cuando declaras tu **ViewHolder**
al inicio de **getView**:

```
final ViewHolder holder=null;
```

**EDIT**

Ok, estoy notando que en la parte del else no estas haciendo nada con la variable holder, de ser asi podrias eliminar el else y declarar, la variable directamente dentro del if cuando le asignas valor de la siguiente forma:

```
if(convertView == null){
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.it_selectitem, null);         
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.precio = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_sa_prec);
    holder.precio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Precio 1");
            list.add("Precio 2");                   
            list.add("** mostrar otro dialog **");
            CharSequence[] items = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);

            bprecios.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if(item == list.size() - 1){ // el ultimo elemento
                        et_nuevoprecio = new EditText(act);
                        et_nuevoprecio.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
                        adnuevoprec = new AlertDialog.Builder(act)
                        .setMessage("Ingrese Nuevo Precio [S/.]")
                        .setTitle("Nuevo Precio")
                        .setView(et_nuevoprecio)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                holder.precio.setText(String.format("%.2f",et_nuevoprecio.getText()));// ERROR HOLDER NO FINAL
                            }
                        })                               
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .create();

                    }else{
                        holder.precio.setText("");  // ERROR HOLDER NO FINAL                            
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();                
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
}else{
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
}
```

Comment: Es apreciada la sugerencia. Olvidé mencionar que le agregué `final` al `viewHolder`, pero obtengo un error que no permite instanciar la variable:
`holder = new ViewHolder();`
Saludos

Comment: Hola, acabo de hacer una edicion basado en tu ultimo comentario

Comment: Tengo entendido que en la funcion getView, el holder primero relaciona los atributos al R.id: `holder.precio = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bt_sa_prec);` en caso de que la variable View sea nula, sino, recupera valor del tag: `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`.
Luego de ello, se setean las propiedades necesarias. Aparte del Button, tengo otros componentes como parte del ítem del LV, el holder del ELSE no concluye ahí. Por ende no puedo colocar final al viewHolder. Edité la sección del codigo.

Comment: Ok, entiendo, pudiste solucionar?, otra idea es declarar otro ViewHolder como final e igualarlo al original asi:    holder=new ViewHolder();     final ViewHolder auxref=holder;  y luego en tu onClick en lugar de utilizar holder utilizas auxref, me avisas si te funciona, sino tengo otras ideas pero requieren de mas tiempo para reestructurar un poco el codigo.